# Create a google cloud app engine instance on a particular region using gcloud command line interface?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine-python

I have started a Google Cloud account and I want to create a Google App Engine Standard instance using Python on a particular region, europe-west2 in this case. How can I do this using gcloud command line tool ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create App Engine in specific region ([gcloud app create documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/create)):

```
gcloud app create --region europe-west2
```

Comment: You can create only 1 instance per project. Choose your region wisely, you won't be able to change it later